# How to automatically generate and draw a smooth curve between two surfaces in JS?

Tags: javascript, rendering, drawing, interpolation, curve-fitting

I would like to be able to automatically generate smooth curves between two (flat) surfaces of DOM elements in JS, similar to the `Curved Connector` in `Google Slides`:

[image]

In GS, you can add a `Curved Connector` and then plug each end into any other anchor point. If the target anchor point belongs to a surface, the connector line will be perpendicular to it. Intermediate points are automatically generated and interpolated to make for a smooth curve. Here are four examples:

[image]

→ Not sure if there is a library out there? Thus far, I have sadly not found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3-graphviz` does all the magic:

- The edges are rendered straight by default, but are automatically bent to avoid other nodes.
- It also has an auto layouting algorithm for [layered/hierarchical graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing).
- It uses [graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) (with the help of [wasm](https://www.google.com/search?q=wasm)) under the hood.

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/Domiii/pen/MWQOQKw?editors=0010):

[image]